# spring model attribute inside jsp 2.0 tag

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsp-tags, spring-form

In my view I have a simple form like this which works :

```
<form:form modelAttribute="user" >
        <form:input path="lastName"/> <br/>
    </form:form>
```

I am trying to make a tag to generate my form like this :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>

<%@ attribute name="model" required="true" type="com.myObject"%>
    <form:form modelAttribute="model" >

        <form:input path="lastName"/> <br/>

    </form:form>
```

called like this :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="ahead" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<ahead:form model="${user}"></ahead:form>
```

But it throw an exception :
Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'model' available as request attribute

If in my tag I write this :

```
<form:form modelAttribute="user" >
```

it works because I guess it finds the attribute "user" in the model

But I want to use the attribute "model" :

```
<%@ attribute name="model" required="true" type="com.myObject"%>
```

because it won't always be called the same in the model.

How can I achieve that ?

thanks

Comment: Currently your form always looks for a attribute named 'model' you should use '${model}' to replace it with the passed in value. Currently it is hardcoded to **model**.

Comment: @M.Deinum Doesn't Spring's `<form:form>` element accept the name of the request attribute for `modelAttribute` and `commandName` attributes?

Comment: Thanks M. Deinum I knew I was not far! Could you add your comment as a response so I can accept it !

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis it does but if you want to fill it dynamically you will have to use an expression instead of a hardcoded value.

Comment: @M.Deinum Oh, I misunderstood the question. `model` is meant to hold the name of the attribute to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form:form modelAttribute="model" >
```

Your current implementation of the tag has a hard-coded name for the `modelAttribute` property it will always be **model** regardless of the value of the passed in attribute is.

To make it dynamic use an expression instead of a hard-coded value.

```
<form:form modelAttribute="${model}" >
```

This will replace the expression with the value of the passed in attribute named `model`.